# To Play or Not to Play? That is the Question.

Tags: probability

I am very bad at problems involving expected return and was hoping some one could help me out.

You are offered a chance to play a game for $48 against 99 other players(100 including you) the game consists of 16 rounds and in each round you have 4 chances to win. The first winner picked in each round gets 30 dollars, the second winner gets 50 dollars, the third gets 30 dollars, and the fourth gets 100 dollars. It is also possible for one person to win more than one of the prizes in one round. The question is what is the expected payout of playing this game?

**Note**: All rounds are independent of each other and each player has an equal chance to win each prize in each round.

Comment: Why not compute the total "invested" by the $100$ people, and the total winnings?

Comment: @MarkBennet That was my first thought, the total paid is 4800, and the total avalable to win is 3360 but the values you can win each round very. So I was unsure if this was the right approach

Comment: Not really a game theory question: the game is entirely random, so there's no strategy involved (except the strategy of not/playing). Removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected winnings for a round are:
$$(1/100)\cdot 30 + (1/100)\cdot 50 + (1/100)\cdot 30 + (1/100) \cdot 100 = \frac{21}{10}$$

Do this 16 times. You expect to win 
$$16 \cdot \frac{21}{10} \$= \frac{168}{5} \$= 33.6 \$$$

Not worth the money.

Payout is $-48\$ + 33.6\$ = -14.4\$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This mmakes sense to me now.

Comment: You have not considered the situation "It is also possible for one person to win more than one of the prizes in one round."

Comment: @Durin:  It doesn't matter.  Each prize is independently distributed, so the rounds don't matter at all except to say how large a given prize is.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider $X_i$ to be the random variable which represents our earning in a given round.
We play 16 rounds so our total earning will be be represented by a random variable $Y=\sum_{n=1}^{16} X_i$.
The expected value of total earning is $E(Y) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + ...E(X_{16})$
Since all random variables represent same event played again and again.
$E(Y) = 16.E(X_1)$

Now lets find $E(X_1)$.
You can win in 4 sub-rounds (the 4 chances) in 15 ways. You can win 1 subround, or 2 subround or 3 or even 4.
Total will be ${4 \choose 1} + {4 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 4} = 15$
However you need to write them down because each way yields different amount you earn. What I've come up with is 
$30, 50, 30, 100, (30 + 50), (30 + 30), (30 + 100), (50 + 30), (50 + 100), (30 + 100), (30 + 50 + 30), (30 + 50 + 100), (30 + 30 + 100) , (50 + 30 + 100), (30 + 50 +30 + 100) $
So total 15 ways.
Now lets calculate probability of each of the 15 ways. It will be $\dfrac 1 {100} * {(\dfrac {99} {100})}^3$ where you win in just 1 subround, $\dfrac 1 {100^2}* {(\dfrac {99} {100})}^2$ where you win two, $\dfrac 1 {100^3}* {(\dfrac {99} {100})}$ where you win 3 and $\dfrac 1 {100^4}$ where you win all four.

The expected value $E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^{15} x_i . P(x_i)$
I won't do calculation here but it comes out to be 
$E(X) = 2.0376279(for-winning-1-subround) + 0.0411642(for-winning-2-subround) +  4.455*10^{-4}(for-winning-3-subround) + 2.1*10^{-6}(for-winning-4-subround) = 2.0792397$

Now $E(Y) = 16.E(X_1) = 16 * 2.0792397 = 33.2678352$

You had invested $48\$$ and you might get back only $33.2678352\$$, so don't play the game.

Comment: This is not quite right.  The chance of winning exactly one specific prize in a round is $\frac 1{100}(\frac {99}{100})^3,$ for example.  This correction will make your solution agree with the other.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Edited my answer with your changes.

Comment: Can someone explain why there is a difference of about 4 cents between this answer and the other?

Comment: For winning two, I get $630 \cdot (\frac 1{100})^2\cdot (\frac {99}{100})^2=0.0617463$  three, I get $630 \cdot (\frac 1{100})^3\cdot \frac {99}{100}=0.0006237$.  I agree on $1$ and $4$

Comment: @RossMillikan I am learning probability myself. I am unable to understand why case of two wins and 3 wins are not agreed upon by you. Please let me know if I am missing out some key thing. In fact a small explanation will be very helpful for me to understand this subject better.